# Using Command Prompt arguments to run a file (with arguments) as an administrator?

Tags: windows, command-line, administrator, privileges, elevation

I am making the menu items called Lock for Microsoft's BitLocker. I've got it all right up to one point: locking HDD partitions requires administrator privileges.
How do I use process paths or CMD or something similar to start an application elevated, with arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the Elevation Powertoy for Vista.  It also works on Windows 7.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2009/01/21/the-elevation-powertoys-and-windows-7.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use the `RUNAS` command and put your application name and its arguments within double quotes.

```
RUNAS /user:machinename\administrator "app arg1 arg2 \"filename with spaces\""
```

Comment: The RUNAS command will execute `C:\Windows\system32\runas.exe` with the given arguments. That application does not require administrator rights and it doesn't work, because I have tried. Anyway, I will try again, but do I need to specify the user? I mean... Can you show me a working example of executing notepad with administrator rights?

Comment: @Vercas: `runas /user:administrator notepad` works for me. I can type some text and save the file in a protected directory.

Comment: It asks me for my password and it does nothing after I type it.